# The "closed" subspaces of topological algebraic structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-algebra

Every set-theoretic model of an algebraic theory gives rise to notion of (algebraically) "closed subset" in a canonical fashion; namely, the closed subsets are those that cannot be escaped via the operations of the algebra. There is also a corresponding closure operator. Now it is a central tenet of categorial logic that we may consider models of algebraic theories in a wide range of categories. Do such models also give rise to (algebraically) "closed subobjects" and a corresponding closure operator?

If so, I am especially interested in the following question. Are the (algebraically) closed subspaces of an algebraic structure internal to $\mathrm{Top}$ precisely those subspaces that are not only inescapable via the operations, but also, topologically closed?

Comment: Parts of this question need to be more precise, but I think that _compactness_ is going to be more topologically interesting than closed-ness, from this angle.  Spectral spaces, for example, provide a wealth of spaces with algebraic structure, but their interesting sub-objects are quasi-compact _opens_.

Comment: @User-33433, thanks for your comment. If you have any specific suggestions for improving the question, that would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what link you are drawing between different uses of the word "closed".  For example, are you trying to consider the algebraic closure of a field as a topological closure? (This actually works I think, but for silly reasons.)  And I wonder what you mean by "operator".  Categorically, I think of something like the algebraic closure as a reflective subcategory / idempotent monad.  But the topological closure operator really is some finitary algebraic thing, so it's not clear to me what connection you're really looking for between the two.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is *no*: there exist subgroups of topological groups that are not closed as subspaces. Let $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ be the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$, viz $\hat{\mathbb{Z}} = \varprojlim_{n} \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$. Then $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a compact Hausdorff topological group (by Tychonoff's theorem, say) and the canonical homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is injective, but its image (which is not discrete) is not a closed subgroup of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. (The closed subgroups of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ are profinite, but there is no way of making $\mathbb{Z}$ into a profinite group.)